# RAPT: Whats wrong with my JDK?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, pygame, renpy

Well, as the question says I have some trouble getting RAPT to run the command:

```
python android.py installsdk
```

It usually returns:

```
    I'm compiling a short test program, to see if you have a working JDK
on your system.


I was unable to use javac to compile a test file. If you haven't
installed the Java Development Kit yet, please download it from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

The JDK is different from the JRE, so it's possible you have Java
without having the JDK. Without a working JDK, I can't continue.
```

I have tried many versions of JDK, I have checked the variable "PATH" and I can run `javac` with no problem. I need a specific version of JDK? (I´m using Python 2.7, 32 bits)

Answer (score 0):

JDK is java development tool kit
JRE is java run-time environment only.
If you have compiled java jar or class file jre is good enough, you do not require jdk.

but if you want to compile java source code you will require javac that comes with JDK.

Try setting JAVA_HOME environment variable.